# perl script call from OpenEdge application causes error: unable to lookup symbol boot_DynaLoader

Tags: perl, openedge, progress-4gl

As part of the AWS migration, we are hosting our application in the EC2 Instance (Amazon Linux 2, 64 Bit) with Perl  5.16.3 at the OS level.  We have created a Perl script to be invoked as an OS shell command for sending application-specific emails.  Amazon SES will be used to sent emails and the script was created with the guideline provided in the Amazon SES documentation. The script is to be used with the Perl version installed at the OS level and we have "shebang" pointing to the '/usr/bin/perl'.

We have tested the script by invoking the same from the Procedure editor and from application-specific "sudo" user and root as well. All these cases worked and we try to do the same from the application and we have the error "/usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/perl: undefined symbol: boot_DynaLoader" . We have also tried invoking simple scripts to display sample messages from the application and we have the same error.

On analysis, we could see that the application uses OE 11.7.8 with Perl 5.6.1. We have also tried prioritizing the PATH to specifically use the "/usr/bin" (when OS level Perl is present)  & "/usr/lib64/perl5" (where the required library files are present) while calling the script from the shell. (Set the PATH and export it just before the call)

We suspect that the error is due to some dependency of the App server call with the OE specific Perl binaries and we tried modifying the shebang to use the OE specific Perl in the DLC path and the "boot_DynaLoader" error is changed and we are not able to use any specific library files with this change.
We also tried updating PATH environment variable in proadsv file and re-started all app/web/db/AdminServers. Still the path is reset to Old one.

We would like to know

1. Why we are not able to invoke the Perl script specific to the one installed at the OS level?
2. Can we have a patch of OE with Perl 5.16.3 or the latest one?
3. Is it possible to update the Perl inside DLC without a patch and its impacts?

Comment: Note that Perl doesn't use `$PATH` to search for libraries, it uses `$PERL5PATH`.

Comment: @choroba:  echo $PERL5LIB
/usr/lib64/perl5

Comment: *"...we could see that the application uses OE 11.7.8 with Perl 5.6.1"* : Why is it using version 5.6.1 ? This version is over 20 years old and probably not supported any longer

Comment: @HåkonHægland: This version is shipped along with OpenEdge

Comment: What is the path to the 5.6.1 perl? I suppose the `/usr/bin/perl` is the system perl with version 5.16.3?

Comment: @HåkonHægland: /usr/bin/perl is the system perl version 5.16.3. which perl commad also returns /usr/bin/perl

Comment: @Vignesh Ok, and what is the path to the 5.6.1. perl?

Comment: @HåkonHægland: this is in th  OE installation folder path and used by the Openedege. For user it always return the OS perl path and bin folder, but cannot execute any script from the OE application.

Comment: @Vignesh What is the path to the OE installation folder? How do you run the OE perl from the command line? If you type `perl --version` I suppose it shows 5.16.3? Obviously you are able to run the OE perl, do you change the path before running it?

Comment: @HåkonHægland: I need to run the script from OS perl and not in OE perl version. Even i type perl -v it shows the OS verision from the OE specific folder. But can see some OE specific pareters are set to use OE perl path and not the OS perl. My problem occurs only when i call perl from the application flow.

Answer (score 1):

I got a reponse from Progress support to update the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable. I did the below statement before the script call and it worked.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/perl5:/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE/:/usr/share/perl5:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following to be useful in similar circumstances:

```
PROVERSION=`cat $DLC/version | awk '{print $3}' | awk -F. '{print $1}'`

if [ $PROVERSION = "12" ]
then
   PERL5LIB="$DLC/perl/lib/5.26.1"
else
   PERL5LIB="$DLC/perl/lib/5.6.1"
fi
export PERL5LIB
```

(I run this in the wrapper script before starting an OpenEdge session.)

Comment: I will check this solution and let you know. Can you please answer the below points also? Can we have a patch of OE with Perl 5.16.3 or the latest one?
Is it possible to update the Perl inside DLC without a patch and its impacts?

Comment: I have never tried. You should talk to Progress tech support for that question.

Comment: I tried the above case but still have the error. I have also tried re-installing perl